# on the uniqueness of special-prime gaps

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I was studying a particular type of prime numbers, and I noticed an interesting property which I wish to prove or disprove.

Consider the set $S = \{10p + 1, 10p + 3, 10p + 7, 10p + 9\}$ (where p is a prime.)

If for any $i$ in S, $i$ is prime, then $i$ is a 'special-prime'. Now, with the help of python, we collected all special-primes $\le10^7$. Computing the differences between successive special-primes, I found that every difference is unique $\le10^7$.

More formally : let $x_i$ denote the ith special-prime. Then for all $i\le10^7$,

$x_{(i+1)} - x_i$ is unique. If I conjecture that this holds for all i, can you help me prove/disprove it.

Comment: What about (599,613) and (719,733)? The only primes between the entries of the pairs are 601, 607, and 727, which are not special. All four elements are then consecutive special primes and both have gap of 14.

Comment: I was trying to say that 599 and 613 are both special primes by your definition, and there are no special primes in between them. $613 - 599 = 14$. Also 719 and 733 are consecutive special primes and $733-719=14$.

Comment: Ok thank you, i made a mistake in the analysis

Comment: Are you referring to https://oeis.org/A227919 or you want a quintuplet where (p,10p+1, 10p+3, 10p+7,10p+9) are all primes? In either case every difference that occurs, occurs infinitely often. @user47033

Answer (score 1):

If *special prime* is defined to be the same as http://oeis.org/A227919, "primes which remain prime when rightmost digit is removed" then the originally posted answer below, about a different interpretation, applies with some obvious modifications. The triple $(p,10p+1,10p+19)$ is conjectured to be prime infinitely often, and most of those prime triples have no other primes between $10p+1$ and $10p+19$, so that difference $d=18$ would occur infinitely often.  Any possible $d$ would repeat at a frequency of $C_d\frac{x}{(\log x)^3}$ up to $x$.

The following interprets the question as asking about clusters $(10p+1,10p+3,10p+7,10p+9)$ all of whose elements are required to be prime (and $p$ also prime), with any element of the cluster designated as "special".

---

The prime $k$-tuplets conjectures predict that all differences $d>4$ that occur are repeated infinitely often at a rate $C_d \frac{x}{(\log x)^6}$ up to $x$, where $C_d$ is a constant computable from $d$.

Differences of $2$ and $4$ are part of the definition of "special prime" quadruples and occur (according to the same conjectures) infinitely often.

The existence of difference $d$ between consecutive $x_i$ implies that

- you can consistently add another requirement that $10p + A$ be prime, where $A$ would cause a difference of $d$ between two $x_i$ values (not necessarily consecutive)
- the conjectures say that for infinitely many primes, $p, 10p+1, 10p+3, 10p+7, 10p+9, 10p+A$ are all prime...
- ...and that for most of those sets there are no additional primes between $10p+1$ and $10p+A$ other than the ones specified in the set, so that the infinitely recurring difference of $d$ is usually between consecutive $x_i$.